# How to update property on object instance instead of original list when using knockout options?

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, binding

I have a simple case where a base list of objects (let's say cars) are bound to a select (dropdownlist). Once the user selects it, he can change the car's price (bid).

However, when changing the price of the selected value the original list used to fill the select gets updated too. Is there a way to detach or clone the selected value so it won't affect the original array?

The whole idea is to use an array as a base for the user to choose so he can customize whatever property he wants in the selected instance and **not** in the original list.

[I have a working fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/zhqvt56c/3/) and the code follows:

HTML:

```
Select a car:<select data-bind="options: availableCars, optionsText: 'Description', value: selectedCar"></select><br/>
You selected: <span data-bind="text: selectedCar().Description"></span>
<br/>
Bid a price: <input type="text" data-bind="value: selectedCar().Price" />
```

JS:

```
var carsListingViewModel = function(availableCars) {
    var self = this;

    self.availableCars = availableCars;
    self.selectedCar = ko.observable();
};

var car = function(make, model, price) {
    var self = this;

    self.Make = ko.observable(make);
    self.Model = ko.observable(model);
    self.Price = ko.observable(price);
    self.Description = ko.computed(function() {
        return self.Make() + ' ' + self.Model() + ' - ' + self.Price();        
    });
};

var allCars = [
    new car('Hyundai', 'i30', 100),
    new car('Chrysler', '300C', 200)
];

var model = new carsListingViewModel(allCars);
ko.applyBindings(model);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to represent *two* domain concepts with *one* observable:

1. Initial / asking(?) price;
2. Bid;

I think you need a seperate constructor function for `bid` observables. You can "spin off" a bid from a car, and use the car's price as the starting bid. If you bind the `select` for cars to a computed writeable observable you can use the `write` bit to also create a fresh bid if the car was changed.

Something like this:

```js
var carsListingViewModel = function(availableCars) {
    var self = this;
    
    self.availableCars = availableCars;
    self.currentBid = ko.observable(null);
    
    _selectedCar = ko.observable();
    self.selectedCar = ko.computed({
      read: _selectedCar,
      write: function(newValue) {
        if (newValue !== _selectedCar()) {
          _selectedCar(newValue);
          self.currentBid(new bid(newValue));
        }
      }
    });
};

var car = function(make, model, price) {
    var self = this;
    
    self.Make = ko.observable(make);
    self.Model = ko.observable(model);
    self.Price = ko.observable(price);
    self.Description = ko.computed(function() {
        return self.Make() + ' ' + self.Model() + ' - ' + self.Price();        
    });
};

var bid = function(car) {
    var self = this;
  
    self.bid = ko.observable(car.Price());
    self.car = ko.observable(car);
};
  
ko.applyBindings(new carsListingViewModel([
    new car('Hyundai', 'i30', 100),
    new car('Chrysler', '300C', 200)
]));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
Select a car:<select data-bind="options: availableCars, optionsText: 'Description', value: selectedCar"></select><br/>
<hr/>
<!-- ko with: currentBid -->
You selected: <span data-bind="text: car().Description"></span>.
Bid a price: <input type="text" data-bind="value: bid" />
<!-- /ko -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Save an additional variable with the original price, and change the computed observable:

```
var car = function(make, model, price) {
  var self = this;

  self.Make = ko.observable(make);
  self.Model = ko.observable(model);
  self.initialPrice = price;
  self.Price = ko.observable(price);
  self.Description = ko.computed(function() {
      return self.Make() + ' ' + self.Model() + ' - ' + self.initialPrice;
  });
};
```

In this case, Description always returns the original value, no matter if self.Price() changes.

The modified sample is here: http://jsfiddle.net/zhqvt56c/4/